# Why is xcode playing sound file without any path for resource?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Ok so the code is suppose to play the sound file when the button is first clicked and play another sound when that same button is clicked again. I put in a folder of sound files all mp3 and it only plays the file yes(I have other sounds like hi, hello, but when I put that in the pathforresouce it does't play them), and I get an nse exception error when I click the button a second time to play the second sound(went into build phases and the sound folder is there but its not playin the other audio files, only yes it plays?). So I took out the path for resource location for both files to check if my sound files are working properly and it's still playing the yes file.  How is this POSSIBLE, when the yes file is only in one location in that sound folder? I even took out that sound folder from my entire project and its still playing yes with no sound file and no pathforresource ?

```
    #import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>
    #import "ViewController.h"


    @interface ViewController ()


    @end
    int flag;

    @implementation ViewController
    AVAudioPlayer *theAudio;
    - (IBAction)Yes:(id)sender {


        if(flag==0){
          //play file one on first button click
            theAudio =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@""ofType:@"mp3"]] error:NULL];

            [theAudio play];
              flag=1;
        }

            else if(flag==1)
            {
          //play file second on first button click


                theAudio =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@""ofType:@"mp3"]] error:NULL];



                [theAudio play];
                           flag=0;

            }


    }
@end
```

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 2):

The leftovers of deleted resources often remain on simulator.

1. Delete app

[image]

2. Clean project and try again.

[image]

Comment: I dont understand that. If my project was alot bigger you are telling me I have to start over from scratch? Suppose hypothetically it took me a month to make an app, and I am having s similar issue, i would hvae to delete my entire 1 month of work an start over just to solve a simple issue?

Comment: @cloudhalo, check my update. It will not hurt your code.

Comment: This is absolutely true. Whenever I see a "hey, the resource is bad on the simulator" deleting the app and then doing a clean build fixes it.