# StoryBoard.InstantiateViewController giving "Unknown class testController in Interface Builder file"

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am working on a Xamarin IOS/monotouch project. 
I have been stuck with this error since some time. These are the lines of code

```
var prfc = this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController ("testController") as testController;
            if (prfc != null) {
                this.PresentViewController(prfc,false,null);}
```

I tried renaming viewcontroller, cleaning and building solution, deleting viewcontroller and adding a new one with another name
I have ensured that all spellings are correct, i have same Viewcontroller name, StoryBoardID, and Restoration ID. This is how I have registered my viewcontroller in Designer partial class

```
[Register ("testController")]
partial class testController
```

Here is my appdelegate.cs code `[Register ("AppDelegate")] public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate { // class-level declarations UIWindow window; public static UIStoryboard Storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName ("MainStoryboard", null); public static UIViewController initialViewController; public override UIWindow Window { get; set; }

```
`[Register ("AppDelegate")] public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate { // class-level declarations UIWindow window; public static UIStoryboard Storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName ("MainStoryboard", null); public static UIViewController initialViewController; public override UIWindow Window { get; set; }
// This method is invoked when the application is about to move from active to inactive state.
// OpenGL applications should use this method to pause.
public override void OnResignActivation (UIApplication application)
{
}

// This method should be used to release shared resources and it should store the application state.
// If your application supports background exection this method is called instead of WillTerminate
// when the user quits.
public override void DidEnterBackground (UIApplication application)
{
}

// This method is called as part of the transiton from background to active state.
public override void WillEnterForeground (UIApplication application)
{
}

// This method is called when the application is about to terminate. Save data, if needed.
public override void WillTerminate (UIApplication application)
{
}
public override void FinishedLaunching (UIApplication application)
{
    window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

    initialViewController = Storyboard.InstantiateInitialViewController () as UIViewController;

    window.RootViewController = initialViewController;
    window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();
    return ;
}
```

}`

I have tried out every possibility but can't fix this. This error is occuring for every new viewcontroller that I add to Storyboard. I am getting a null when I call InstantiateViewController. I have tried cleaning and rebuilding. It works on simulator, but not on device

Comment: Possibly your simulator cache corrupted. Clean your project as described here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26206041/why-is-xcode-playing-sound-file-without-any-path-for-resource/26207323#26207323

Comment: @orkenstein I have tried cleaning and rebuilding. Forgot to mention, it works on simulator, but not on device

Comment: Ok, any differences between Simulator and Device target/schema?

Comment: @orkenstein Yeah. That was the issue. I was targeting ios 7.1 and now it works after bringing down it to 7.0. Thank You...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was as pointed out by @orkenstein. I was targeting 7.1 whereas was testing on a 7.0 device